# SQOOP: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database

Tags: mysql, database, hadoop, sqoop

I'm working on SQOOP on multinode setup (7 nodes).

1. CLIENT
2. NAMENODE
3. SECONDARY NAMENODE
4. JOBTRACKER
5. DATANODE 1
6. DATANODE 2
7. DATANODE 3

On **Client Node** I have installed hadoop, sqoop.
On **Other Nodes** only Hadoop is installed.

I'm using **mySQL**. I have created database **GAME_OF_THRONES**. I have created table **kings_battles** as below:

> create table kings_battles(name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, year INT NOT
>   NULL, battle_number INT NOT NULL, attacker_king VARCHAR(50),
>   defender_king VARCHAR(50), attacker_1 VARCHAR(50), attacker_2
>   VARCHAR(50), attacker_3 VARCHAR(50), attacker_4 VARCHAR(50),
>   defender_1 VARCHAR(50), defender_2 VARCHAR(50), defender_3
>   VARCHAR(50), defender_4 VARCHAR(50), attacker_outcome VARCHAR(50),
>   battle_type VARCHAR(50), major_death TINYINT, major_capture TINYINT,
>   attacker_size INT, defender_size INT, attacker_commander VARCHAR(50),
>   defender_commander VARCHAR(50), summer TINYINT, location VARCHAR(50),
>   region VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(battle_number));

But I'm getting error while **executing sqoop export command** from client node:

**Command:**

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/GAME_OF_THRONES --table
kings_battles --username root --password hadoop123 --export-dir
/input/5kings_battles.csv
```

**Error:**

```
Error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'GAME_OF_THRONES'
```

I checked database and table are created in Client Node using 
**mysql -u root -p**

**How can I resolve this error.. like is port number, ip address required.?
Can anyone help me out. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems your database name is `game_of_thrones` instead of `GAME_OF_THRONES`.

Try:

`sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/game_of_thrones --table kings_battles --username root --password hadoop123 --export-dir /input/5kings_battles.csv`

To sure about case sensitivity of database names, you can check **list of all the databases** using command-

`sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/ --username root --password hadoop123`

Comment: Hi @devツ : Thanks for help. I have checked using ur given query and using show databases; also. The database name is GAME_OF_THRONES and table name is kings_battles. Also i tried exporting using db name game_of_thrones but it gave me unknown database 'game_of_thrones' error

Comment: Should I use ip address of the node i.e client node. but while trying with ip address it displays connection refused. Do I need to Grant any privileges ?

Comment: @techGaurdian mysql and sqoop installed on same machine?

Comment: yes. copied the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 jar file inside /home/notroot/lab/software/sqoop-1.4.0-incubating/lib

Comment: Am I going the right way ? or have I missed something

Answer (score 0):

You must change the connection chain with your hostname instead of localhost.

> sqoop export --connect
>   jdbc:mysql:/ip-172-31-75-48.ec2.internal/game_of_thrones --table
>   kings_battles --username root --password hadoop123 --export-dir
>   /input/5kings_battles.csv

and it will work because it's a distribution problem of YARN.

to find your hostname, just write hostname in shell.